# Best time to identify geolocation?

Tags: web-applications, geolocation, ip

I have been tasked with creating a small desktop client that will report to a central web server its location. Could I just capture the incoming IP address when it requests the web page? Will that be enough to identify it? Or should I get the external IP from the client first and post that? Just want to know at what point in the entire transaction will get me the most accurate location.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the ipv4 (or ipv6) protocols give any guarantees about the exact location of an ip address.

Geolocation ([example](http://www.geobytes.com/iplocator.htm)) usually works by automatically looking up an IP address on a WHOIS service and retrieving the registrant's physical address.

If you want an accurate location, the client will have to voluntarily sent it.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it and that makes more sense coming from the client. If you were to get it at the server, it may have bounced around before it got there. Thanks for your advice.